# Magento: email_template not loading in custom module

Tags: zend-framework, email, templates, magento

I've created my own custom contact form module. In `postAction()` function, in the `IndexController.php` I have

```
$mailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
```

Doing a console log shows that nothing gets stored in the variable. Why would this be? The default contacts module loads it fine, so why should anything be different here?

Also, when making the call to actually send the mail it always throws an Exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT  = 'quotes/email/recipient_email';
const XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER     = 'quotes/email/sender_email_identity';
const XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE   = 'quotes/email/email_template';
```

`$mailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');`

/* @var $mailTemplate Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template */

```
                $mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend'))
                    ->sendTransactional(
                    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
                    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER),
                    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT),
                    null,
                    array('data' => $postObject)`
                );
```

This should allow you to send the template as you need it.

You will need this bit of XML in your config.xml

```
    <template>
        <email>
            <quotes_email_email_template translate="label" module="quotes">
                <label>Quote Form</label>
                <file>quote_form.html</file>
                <type>text</type>
            </quotes_email_email_template>
        </email>
    </template>


    <default>
        <quotes>
            <quotes>
                <enabled>1</enabled>
            </quotes>
            <email>
                <recipient_email><![CDATA[hello@example.com]]></recipient_email>
                <sender_email_identity>custom2</sender_email_identity>
                <email_template>quotes_email_email_template</email_template>
            </email>
        </quotes>
    </default>
```

This is an example from Mage_Quotes module that allows a form to send a quote for a product.

Comment: Your post is correct however I traced it to be an error with my local wamp setup & an SMTP error. My method worked fine on my production site. Thanks though!